# Missing Print Job History in Lexmark Printers

Tags: printing, network-printer, laser-printer, lexmark-printer, color-printer

We recently purchased different Lexmark printer models to replace our previous aging printers in our network.

The models are including color laser printer C4300 Series and black and white XM3200 Series like Lexmark C4342 and M3250, these printers don't have a basic print job history as far as we could go.

We asked the Lexmark service provider shop and the vendor's support separately, first, they directed us to different wrong locations on the Printers' web access UI, and then the Lexmark support claimed:

> We've verified that the print job history cannot be accessed for security purposes.

While all other printers and copiers (that we have worked with at least) are providing this basic report that is essential for troubleshooting and powering helpdesk techs to be able to assist users when they have a printing problem, which "**Security Purpose**" stopped Lexmark (and not other brands) from giving access (to the owners) to this basic reports if they are honest and actually this report exist?

Thanks for your time and appreciate it if you can provide some insight into this issue.

Comment: A work-around: set up a *network print server* and view logs.

Comment: Note that anything the reduces complexity and reduces the  attack surface will , almost  by definition,  improve security. So "improved security" is always a good positive claim to make when reducing functionality :) - I wouldn't be surprised that removing functionality is in reality a commercial choice, for example designed to better postion "an enterprise *solution"* like a print server with accounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexmark support came back to solve the mystery they had made. Here is their quote, I leave it here for your consideration and judgement:

> Apologies for any confusion. ... Viewing the print job history can only be done from one of the Solutions we offer for our devices- [Cloud Print Management](https://www.lexmark.com/en_au/solutions/lexmark-cloud-services/cloud-print-management.html).

Comment: Hahaha - indeed as I had already expected - *"I wouldn't be surprised that removing functionality is in reality a commercial choice, for example designed to better postion "an enterprise solution""*

Answer (score 0):

I note that "secure printing" is on the feature list for the C4300 Series.

"secure printing" means hiding the print jobs from second or third party users.

It may be that the implementation of 'secure printing' doesn't work the way you want, or even that you don't want 'secure printing' at all. Support for mid or low-level printers is poor to non-existent, but I'll take Canon's word for it that the printer you have doesn't do what you want.

Comment: The question is about Security "Purpose" claim, not Secure Printing. By the way one of the important features of "Secure Printing" is Audit Trails: Secure printing systems keep detailed logs of print activities, including user IDs, print times, and printer locations. This can help monitor and track any suspicious or unauthorized printing activities.

Comment: @user, you asked about the purpose of this security feature. I explained that the purpose is to provide secure printing. If you don't like the answers, it means you should change the question to elicit different responses.